# Applying multiple authentication strategies in Symfony3

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a site that have a `/user` path, which returns, as you may guess, a current user that is logged in in my application.
My app serves both as web application and API for mobile app.

The requirement that needs to be met:

For mobile API: 
`/user` should check if query params (user_id and auth_token) identify user in my database. If so, return data for this user (in a stateless way)

For web API: 
`/user` should check if current request was previously authenticated via `login_form`.

I had a try with `guard` for mobile and `login_form` for web and shared context but when `stateless: false` is set, calling `/user` as mobile API grants a cookie (which allows to use app URLs as a web app user - permission issue).

I also tried to access context of a `login_form` (to pull current user) when processing as mobile app, but with no luck.

Is there a valid elegant solution for such situation?
`/user` authenticated with either query params (stateless) or session cookie?

Comment: why not using something like [JWS](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwianpya99_TAhXBVywKHahWA4UQFghAMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fknpuniversity.com%2Fscreencast%2Fsymfony-rest4%2Fjwt-guard-authenticator&usg=AFQjCNEoCxyUhSYipht5CcRfFgzT7uvlVQ&sig2=UjPxmBAcrWKjaN3PDZLvhg) for both ways?

Comment: That was my initial recommendation, but we're setting top-level cookie for domain which allows us to idenfity user on different apps within the domain, so JWT would break things.

Comment: /user shoud be under secured_area in security. Symfony will check for credentials independently of how they where created (login form or access token in the request).